# Can we point to other Stack Exchange communities inside a tag description?

Tags: discussion, tags, review

While reviewing, I came across a tag excerpt update that points a user towards another community and I didn't know if I could approve this or had to reject this:

[image]

Personally, I'm convinced this kind of information doesn't belong there, but I wanted to know if this is common practice?

Comment: The tag should explain which type of questions should carry the tag. If it is clear that a certain class of questions shouldn't be asked but instead are better served on another venue it is relevant to mention that info and guide the few users that actual read the excerpt. So yes, if that info is factual correct and the receiving end, opendata,se in this case, also agrees with taking those questions, that info is OK and should be accepted

Answer (score 4):

It is fine to use the tag wiki descriptions to reinforce a site's scope.

For example, at GIS the [tag wiki for software-recommendations](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations) says:

> Questions seeking software recommendations are better asked at the
>   Software Recommendations Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

If there are scope issues with a tag -- *some* questions about X are ok and *others* aren't here but work over there -- then it's fine to clarify that in the tag wiki, as others have said.  However, the tag wiki (or any other on-site documentation, like help/on-topic) should make it really clear that this is only for questions that wouldn't be welcome here.  You don't want readers to get the message that all questions about X should be asked there.  (Not everybody will make the connection that *you have a tag for it* so it must be more nuanced.)

With that in mind, a good practice for this kind of redirection is to start with what's ok, then say what's not, and finally name the other site for those cases.  The edit in this question reverses those, leading with the link to the other site.  It would be better to end that wiki with:

> Questions about a particular Linked Data dataset or that are not closely related to programming are not on topic on (whatever site you got this from).  Consider asking on (link to other site) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I think it's necessary.

For instance, smartphone apps are off-topic at [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com). But we still occasionally get questions about them, because a lot of popular web applications have smartphone companion apps. For instance, the [tag wiki for Dropbox](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/dropbox/info) says, in part:

> - If your question is about the PC or Mac app, it may already have an answer at [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dropbox).
> - If your question is about the Android app, it may already have an answer at [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dropbox).
> - If your question is about the iOS app, it may already have an answer at [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dropbox).

The tag wikis on the other sites have similar language.

The excerpt says:

> For questions about the web interface to the Dropbox cross-platform file synchronisation utility. Questions regarding installed Dropbox applications on devices should be asked on other SE sites.